# What does "it()" stand for in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, bdd

Just curious what the function name it() stands for in the Jasmine Javascript test framework. Does it stand for something like "independent test" or something?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's just language semantics. `it` expects something, `it` does something, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the question. I filed a pull request for the Jasmine documentation and it just got merged: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/1772

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It means "it", as in the word "it".  As in the test declaration reads like a sentence. You `describe` an object by what `it` does. Simple as that.

For example:

> Bowling ball is round
>
> Bowling ball has 3 holes

Might translate to a test hierarchy like this:

```
Bowling Ball
  it is round
  it has three holes
```

Which would translate to the following testing setup:

```
describe(BowlingBall, function() {
  it('is round', function() {});
  it('has three holes', function() {});
});
```

So because it reads well, it just becomes the way you separate individual test cases. It also encourages you to write your test description in a consistent manner because `it` is part of the sentence that describes the test, which makes your test suite more readable over the long term.

In the end BDD is *all* about readability for the test writer.  So this is simply sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like that. :)

It's a block to make more readable your specs. In particular, you can write stuff like this:

```
describe("When the user clicks the button", function() {
    it("renders the div with class .hello", function() {
        // your assertion here
    });
});
```

So you're test output in the console looks like:

```
When the user clicks the button renders the div with class .hello
```